# python logging __name__ and packaging

Tags: python, logging

The [official python logging documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html?highlight=logging#logger-objects) says this:

> The name is potentially a period-separated hierarchical value, like
>   foo.bar.baz (though it could also be just plain foo, for example).
>   Loggers that are further down in the hierarchical list are children of
>   loggers higher up in the list. For example, given a logger with a name
>   of foo, loggers with names of foo.bar, foo.bar.baz, and foo.bam are
>   all descendants of foo. The logger name hierarchy is analogous to the
>   Python package hierarchy, and identical to it if you organise your
>   loggers on a per-module basis using the recommended construction
>   logging.getLogger(__name__). That’s because in a module, __name__ is
>   the module’s name in the Python package namespace.

But I have found that last sentence not to be strictly true.  The value of `__name__` seems to depend on how a module is imported.  The following demonstrates this:

Given two modules, foo and bar both in package pkg:

This is **foo**:

```
def showFoosName():
    print __name__
```

and this is **bar**:

```
from pkg import foo
if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo.showFoosName()
```

running bar produces

```
pkg.foo
```

However, if we introduce **baz** into package pkg, which imports foo simply as foo, which is legal because both are in the same package:

```
import foo
if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo.showFoosName()
```

running baz produces

```
foo
```

Now bringing this discussion back to logging and logging configuration, it seems that the python logging recommendation of naming loggers with `__name__` only holds good if imports within a package are coded with `from pkg import bar` syntax.  This is not what I would have expected.  I would have thought that `__name__`'s value would be independent of how it was imported.

Comment: If you're launching `baz.py` from the `pkg` directory, then there *is* no package `pkg`: in that scenario the `pkg` folder is not a package, but a root of `sys.path`. This is one of the reasons why you shouldn't mix executable scripts in among your folder structure of importable packages.

Comment: @DanielPryden: Given the reported results of running `bar`, I'm inclined to think `pkg` was both a package *and* a `sys.path` entry, but there are other possibilities, such as `bar` not actually being in `pkg`. In any case, I would agree that mixing scripts in with the structure of a package is something to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing about Python packages and modules is that, like everything else in Python, they are dynamic. The `__name__` of each module depends on where it is relative to the Python root paths (on `sys.path`). So if you have a folder named `pkg`, even if it contains an `__init__.py`, it is not actually a "package" if it is on `sys.path` directly. If the `pkg` folder is on `sys.path` directly (for example, because you launched the Python interpreter there), then it is not a package, and any `.py` files inside it are top-level modules, not modules inside any package. Thus if you have `foo.py` inside the `pkg` folder, when you launch the Python interpreter from inside `pkg`, `foo.py`'s real, official name *is* `foo`, not `pkg.foo`.

Unless the folder that *contains* `pkg` is on `sys.path`, there *is* no package `pkg` -- `from pkg import foo` would fail with an `ImportError`. And if both `pkg` and the folder containing `pkg` are both on `sys.path`, then your Python path is malformed, and you have two separate importable modules, `pkg.foo` and `foo` (with independent copies of all their globals!).

To resolve this kind of problem, it's a best practice to separate executable scripts and importable modules and packages from each other. This allows you to put all your importable modules and packages into a common place (normally, under `site-packages` for your Python installation), and your executable scripts can import them using the full name, regardless of where the scripts are located (typically, someplace like `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`).

Answer (score 1):

This is a symptom of your import path being broken. You have both `pkg` and its containing directory on your path, causing `foo.py` to correspond to *two separate modules*, `foo` and `pkg.foo`.

Likely, the directory containing `pkg` is on your import path, but you are running `bar.py` and `baz.py` directly by file name, causing `pkg` itself to be on the path too. Running

```
python -m pkg.bar
```

or

```
python -m pkg.baz
```

should prevent `pkg` from being added to the path.

That's only one possible way your import path could have been messed up. We can't really tell. Reading up on the Python import system should help; [here's one good resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time).